# Primefaces Popup Form Based Login

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, authentication, primefaces

I have the following problem. I have built a FORM based login in using PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT, JSF2.2 and Glassfish 4.0.

The login is working if I use it on a seperate login page. If I however want to build a login using a PF Popup as shown in the showcase example on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf I get logged in, but not forwarded to the protected site.

I only get forwarded, if I click on a link that has the protected area as target and only afterwards clicking on the login dialog link.

It seems that the form based login only works if I can somehow target the protected area, when using the login dialog. Can I do this using a loginBean or can I do this using just the FORM based authentication? Can someone point me towards a possible solution? I am new to this environment and could not find solutions regarding form based logins combined with popup dialog boxes.

Thanks a lot.

link to trigger popup:

```
<h:outputLink id="loginLink" value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PF('dlg').show()" title="login" class="sign_in" >Sign in here!</h:outputLink>
```

login form:

```
    <p:dialog id="logindialog" header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">  
        <h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action='j_security_check';" prependId="false">  
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000" />  
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
                 <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username:" />
                <p:inputText id="j_username" />
                <p:tooltip for="j_username" value="Bitte Benutzernamen eingeben" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />  
                <p:password id="j_password" />
                <p:tooltip for="j_password" value="Bitte Passwort eingeben" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" />
                <f:facet name="footer">  
                        <div style="text-align: center">
                        <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false" oncomplete="app/index?faces-redirect=true"/> 
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>  
     </p:dialog>
```

web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
          <display-name>Mofnug Pages</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
              <web-resource-name>Protected Mofnug Area</web-resource-name>
              <description></description>
              <url-pattern>/faces/app/*</url-pattern>
              <http-method>GET</http-method>
              <http-method>POST</http-method>
              <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
              <http-method>PUT</http-method>
              <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
              <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
              <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
              <description/>
              <role-name>admin</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
          <user-data-constraint>
              <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
          </user-data-constraint>
      </security-constraint>

      <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>mofnug</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/index.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/loginerror.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like oncomplete="/app/index" on your output Link that opens the dialog?